# How can 405: Not allowed on DELETE be resolved with a C# endpoint when URL and CORS are configured?

Tags: c#, rest, react-redux

React-Redux API call:
The API variable is correct as it works on POST on this same endpoint. I added the rowId to the end of the URL because I read that it was needed for Delete.

```
export const CIBC_Preauth_Delete = (rowId, newStateData) => (dispatch, getState) => {

    dispatch({
        type: ActionTypes.CIBC_PREAUTH_LOADED,
        payload: newStateData
    });

    dispatch({
        type: ActionTypes.CIBC_PREAUTH_UPDATING
    });
    var init = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(fetchInit(getState)));
    init.body = JSON.stringify({ user:{...init.body.user},id: rowId, verb:"DELETE" });
    var myReq = new Request(`${API}/CIBCPreAuth?id=${rowId}`, init);

    return fetch(myReq)
        .then((response) => {
            if (response.ok) {
                return response;
            }
            else {
                var error = new Error("Error " + response.statusText);
                error.response = response;
                throw error;
            }
        }, (error) => {
            var err = new Error(error.message);
            throw err;
        })
        .then((response) => { return response.json() })
        .then((CIBCPreAuth) => {
            if (CIBCPreAuth !== "False")
                dispatch({
                    type: ActionTypes.CIBC_PREAUTH_UPDATESAVED,
                    payload: CIBCPreAuth
                })
            else
                CurrentPage_Update({ componentId: 'NotAllowed' });
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            return dispatch({
                type: ActionTypes.CIBC_PREAUTH_UPDATEFAILED,
                payload: err.message
            })
        });
}
```

API Endpoint:

```
 [HttpDelete]
        [Route("CIBCPreAuth/{id}")]
        public async Task<string> DeletePreAuth(int id)
        {
            try
            {
                string? name = MCA.APIUtilities.GetName(HttpContext);
                if (name is not null)
                {
                    var user = await new User(name, _DevContext).Initialize();
                    if (user.IsAdmin() || user.IsInRole("BUS_CIBCPreAuth"))
                    {
                        var ret = await CIBC.DeletePreauth(_db, id);
                        return ret.ToString();
                    }
                    return "{'notAllowed':true}";
                }
                else
                {
                    return "{'error':'User identity not detected'}";
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return $"Error: {ex.Message}";
            }
        }
```

Again aside from the and the function call this is identical to the POST function.

Here is my CORS configuration:

```
builder.Services.AddCors(opt =>
{
    opt.AddPolicy("CORS", policy =>
        {
            policy.WithOrigins("http://localhost:3000")
            .AllowAnyHeader()
            .AllowCredentials()
            .AllowAnyMethod();
        });
});
```

Everything I have read says that this is correctly configured but it is still throwing the 405.  When I run it through the SwaggerUI however, it works correctly. This suggests to me that the problem is in the React code but I am not seeing it.

**EDIT**

When stepping through the code in Javascript the breakpoint is not even stopping in the `CIBC_Preauth_Delete` function. It touches the function name then goes to the end without touching the first dispatch. I am getting no errors or warnings in my code though so I have nothing to debug with.

**UPDATE**

When attempting the same call I modified the calling code to be the same as the POST call.  I added a `key:value` to the body of `"verb":"DELETE"` in an attempt to reach the server. On the server I added an if/then for the potential verbs passed in, with the default being the original fetch data.

The fetch still works as it is supposed to, but the same function cannot be entered stepping through code when using the delete. Here is the calling function:

```
     import { CIBC_Payment_Delete } from 'CIBCPreAuthCreators';

     const CIBC_PreauthDelete = (RowId, NewStateData) => { dispatch(CIBC_Preauth_Delete(RowId, NewStateData)) };
    

    const deleteFn = (row, rowData) => {
        let newData;
        let rowId = row.id;
        let check = rowData.getElementsByClassName(`row_${row.id}_col_deleteCheck`)
        if (check[0]) check = check[0];
        try {
            if (check) {
                if (check.checked) {
                    //remove this row from state array
                    newData = preAuth.preAuthData.filter((obj) => { return obj.id !== rowId });
                    CIBC_Preauth_Delete(rowId, newData); //remove from database
                }
            }
            else {
                newData = preAuth.preAuthData.filter((obj) => { return obj.id !== rowId });
                CIBC_PreauthDelete(rowId, newData); //remove from database
            }
        }
        catch (ex) {
            console.log(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

The import for the fetch is in the same import statement. I have updated my `CIBC_Preauth_Delete()` function above.